# avoiding 'dot gain' : preparing inner sleeve design in illustrator for printing on uncoated stock

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design, print-production, color-conversion

I'm preparing album cover artwork -- I'm going to print some vinyl. The mfr recommends a disco jacket as the inner sleeve for 180g vinyl because it resists the vinyl tearing a hole over time. Their [description](https://www.furnacemfg.com/vinyl/print-packaging-options/) says these disco jackets are printed on 12 pt board stock. I'd like to use their upgrade option and print the *uncoated* side because I want the inner sleeve to truly feel like a relic from a century ago. The mfr has a strong warning about **dot gain** when printing uncoated stock:

> **Unfinished / Uncoated** stock is what you are looking for if you want no trace of gloss whatsoever. Your design is printed straight onto uncoated paper stock – no gloss, no finishing coat – just ink and paper. Unfinished stock creates very different results than coated stock due to how the ink is absorbed into the paper during the printing process. If you would like to work with unfinished stock, make sure you or your designer has experience designing for uncoated print as there will be “dot gain” that darkens up the design and makes proofing totally unpredictable. Most newbies are disappointed with the look of their graphics when printed on uncoated stock because they don’t properly compensate for this dot-gain-darkening phenomenon. We warn you now, you are responsible for knowing how to design for uncoated and we can’t credit you or redo your print if you are unhappy with the outcome so ask a lot of questions and plan for the worse.

My design will have a ww1 trench map like [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vimy-Sheet36c_SW3_Edition_8a_10-02-17.jpg) or perhaps [this french one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Deux_cartes_sur_les_journ%C3%A9es_de_la_bataille_de_la_Marne_(entre_Meaux_et_le_Multien),_6,_7,_8_et_9_septembre_1914.jpg) on the front and I plan to print lyrics and credits in a plain font (like garamond) on the back with perhaps some simple vector graphics.

My question is this: **How should I prepare my artwork to avoid dot gain problems when printing on uncoated stock?** I'd *like* to print the disco jackets on the 12 pt board stock, but may opt for the uncoated 70lb paper sleeve. I want the uncoated stock because I expect it will have that vintage old-book feeling. I would point out that my lyrics and credits text will probably just be laid out with Adobe Garamond as a font, presumably on a white background, but the trench maps from wikipedia appear to already have a yellowed patina coloring. I'd like my lyrics/credits to match the 'yellowness' of the trench map. Should I add yellowed paper backgrounds to my designs? I fear that adding some scanned parchment pattern as background image could easily result in a very artificial-looking result. I guess I could stain some watercolor paper with tea or coffee and scan it, but worry that the CMYK printing might easily look very fake. This brings up another question: **What is a good method for matching my new lyrics/credits text match the yellowed look of the original map, and look authentically old?** Keep in mind I'm dealing with a) uncoated stock and b) concerned about it looking fake -- e.g., using some small tiled parchment image seems like a bad idea.

Most critically, I'd like to make sure the credits are legible and the trench map looks authentic. I understand that rich blacks reduce clarity and I should probably color text with C/M/Y/K plain black of 0/0/0/100. I also have noticed that when I open those images from wikipedia in photoshop that they are RGB. If I open the document in PS and use the eyedropper tool to sample one of the trench map blacks, I see C/M/Y/K values for a couple of black pixels of 22/22/0/96 or 23/27/0/88, which appears to be some kind of 'rich black' rather than a 'plain black'. Mfr says artwork should be provided as CMYK, not RGB, so I'm wondering what steps I should take to convert the image.

**EDIT:** Rafael asked if this would be offset or digital job. The [mfr's FAQ](https://www.furnacemfg.com/design-faq/#1513634390692-552edaa8-eba3) suggests that they use offset printing for jackets (presumably including disco jackets or printed sleeves):

> Jackets, booklets, inserts, vinyl record labels, etc are all printed using the offset process. We can even print full-color images onto CDs and DVDs using offset. Sometime, short run inserts and fold-overs covers can be printed using a high quality digital press because they now offer the same great look and quality of offset at a lower price point.

Comment: Is it going to be a digital print? or is a long run on sheetfed offset?

Comment: @Rafael that is a good question, and I don't yet know. Their [FAQ](https://www.furnacemfg.com/design-faq/#1513634390692-552edaa8-eba3) suggests that it will be a short run offset -- I'm only printing 500. Will edit question to provide add'l detail.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! Your question is well written and easy to understand. But you are asking too many questions at a time. To answer this I feel I would almost have to do the design for you and then spend time describing and illustrating the process and all the choices there are along the way.  You need to split your question into chunks. Since you're a new user and have put so much effort into writing this, I'll put some effort into commenting:

Comment: The part about how to prepare artwork for uncoated paper is a good question on its own. It would be helpful if you knew which color profile the print house recommends for uncoated paper. Whether you should print the background texture or not is a matter of taste. We can't answer that for you. Questions you could ask could be about how to recreate/match the map texture or how to remove it. Or maybe how to first remove it and then add another texture. (You seem to assume that uncoated paper is yellowish. That isn't necessarily true. It could be white. You have to ask the print shop about that.)

Comment: The part about separating the images to get the black lines plain 100% black is a whole question on its own. Plain black looks clean because it most commonly prints *on top of* the underlying objects. Then there's no misalignment. But in these old scans, you don't know what's below the black. It's advanced stuff and perhaps not even possible. I think I would just live with the rich black I get when converting to the proper CMYK profile. Perhaps even choosing the same color for the credits so they match. But trying different methods would be part of the time I would spend on such a job.

Comment: @Wolff TYVM! I'm not sure what you mean by 'color profile the print house recommends'. I quoted their site in my OP. I do understand that uncoated paper could still be white. When I say vintage 'feel' I refer to how it feels to touch, ie like money, not glossy. i was also thinking that trying to simulate the old parchment look might be more convincing if the uncoated paper absorbs the ink a bit-or it might not? I think rich black seems nice for the trench map, but the pile-up of different inks might not help with the small (9pt) text on lyrics/credits.

Comment: A color profile is what enables a conversion from RGB to CMYK. There is no such thing as "just CMYK" (or "just RGB" for that matter). The print house follows some standard and you need to use the color profile they provide to able to preserve the colors from the original RGB as well as possible. The image you want use isn't extremely sensitive though. As long as you make the background texture a bit on the light side it can't go terribly wrong. So the brown might be a little different from what you expect, but so what? It's worse with images with lots of detail in the shadows.

Comment: And yes, rich black isn't recommended for small texts, so that's a dilemma. Perhaps I would manipulate the scan so the black becomes the same CMYK values as the black text on top of the yellowish background. But again, it should have its own question. Too much to explain in comments.

Comment: Regarding printing on the uncoated side of C1S - the uncoated side is not prepared for printing since it's not sized properly. I don't know if your vendor would even agree to it since it creates a number of print production problems. Looking at your artwork, if you want an uncoated feel, find out if the vendor has matte coated card stock in that weight/caliper. This will give the ink an opportunity to "stand up" a bit on the paper. Can't say it's never been done, in all the years I spent in custom packaging, working with board from 10pt.- 24 pt. C1S, we never printed on the uncoated side.

Comment: @JeffK, at my job we've offset-printed a few LP covers on the uncoated side. It's like the backside of postcard board. You are right that it's a very poor piece of uncoated stock, but it *is* a "thing". As I recall it has mostly been just black or black and a spot color. It does give a "worn" or "authentic" look fitting for some genres. Not really good for photos, but could be OK for sharper graphics if you like the look.